# Relaciones Custom Post Types WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo un problema con 2 CTP, estoy lo estoy haciendo con el Plugin ToolSet.

Uno CTP se llama Ciudades y el segundo se llama Poblaciones, con ToolSet, los he creado y he hecho una relación Uno a Muchos.

Una ciudad puede tener muchas poblaciones.

Imprimo todas las ciudades utilizando una vista en una pagina, utilizo campo titulo `[wpv-post-title]` y un campo llamado titulo con link `[wpv-post-link]`, todo ello en una tabla, quisiera saber como hacer para que cuando pinche en una ciudad, me devuelva el listado de las poblaciones, no el single de esa ciudad.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, lo único que tenia que hacer era una vista que filtrara por la ciudad elegida o donde pinchaba, en la single-page o plantilla single de la ciudad, añadia esa vista y salen las poblaciones de esa ciudad.

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: No olvides marcar tu aporte como aceptado, así los demás nos enteramos que esto es la solución